# Constructing a structured scalar from bytes

Tags: python, numpy

I've found myself using numpy dtypes in place of ctypes recently for handling binary data, with something like:

```
dt = np.dtype([
    ('header', np.uint16),
    ('points', ([
        ('x', np.int32),
        ('y', np.int32),
    ], (16,))),
])
buffer = file_like.read(dt.itemsize)  # type: bytes
```

For the purpose of testing, you can assume that

```
buffer = bytes(range(dt.itemsize))
```

I've been struggling to find a nice equivalent to `ctypes.from_buffer`. Some options I can come up with are:

1. `data = np.array(buffer).view(dt)[()]`
2. `data = np.ndarray(shape=(), buffer=buffer, dt=dt)[()]`
3. `data = np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype=dt).squeeze(axis=-1)[()]`

These all seem rather convoluted - am I missing a better way?

Comment: What's the problem?  It's natural for `numpy` functions to produce `ndarray` objects.  What's the purpose of the `[()]` indexing?

Comment: `np.ndarray(1,dt,buffer)[0]` I guess? That's fairly short

Comment: @hpaulj I believe OP wants to get a `np.void` object (a scalar) instead of `np.ndarray`

Answer (score 0):

`data = np.void(buffer).view(dt)` has the desired properties:

- Short
- Returns a scalar
- Throws `ValueError: new type not compatible with array.` if `len(buffer) != dtype.itemsize`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21280168)

Comment: @DougR. The author of the question is answering his own question.  That is allowed, if not common.  And if he thinks it's relevant it is.

Comment: Eric, I was exploring `np.void` (and `np.record` which is a subclass), and found it only took, or at least only used, the buffer.  Applying `astype` to it does make sense.  But since I'm not in the habit of constructing 'scalar' numpy items - numeric or otherwise - I don't see as that much of an improvement over the other tries.  It's slower.  `ndarray` is fastest.